# R - How to delete/exclude rows in a table that are in another table

Tags: r

I have 2 data.tables, 'a' and 'b'. 'b' is a proper subset of 'a'. I would like to generate a table 'c' that contains everything that is in 'a' but not in 'b'. I am sure there is a trivial way to do this, just not sure how.

Comment: What objects are they?  Are they `matricies`? `data.frames`? `data.tables`?  In the simplest case, you want `a[!(b %in% a)]`.  Also take a look at `help(setdiff)`.

Comment: They are data.tables, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
# to ensure we get the same `start'
set.seed(667)
# genrate a data.frame `a` with some data
a <- data.frame(z = sample(c(c(4,7),11,NA),  4, rep = TRUE), 
                x = sample(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6),  4, rep=TRUE), 
                y = sample(c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16),  4, rep=TRUE))
# make a subset `b'
b <- a[1:2,]
# lets have a look at `a' and `b'
a
   z x  y
1  4 6 12
2  7 6 13
3 NA 5 14
4 11 6 16
b
  z x  y
1 4 6 12
2 7 6 13
b
# small function to solve your problme
setdiff.data.frame <- function(a,b) a[!duplicated( rbind(b,a) )[-seq_len(nrow(b))],]
# genrate c
c <- setdiff.data.frame(a,b)
# and let's see `c'
c
   z x  y
3 NA 5 14
4 11 6 16
```

Also, pengyu wrote a function for the same, you can [find it on github](https://github.com/pengyu/pytools/blob/master/R_src/setdiff.data.frame/setdiff.data.frame.R).

Here is a somewhat roundabout way transforming it to matrices, but as you will see it does creates some extra work.

```
A <- data.matrix(a, rownames.force = TRUE)
B <- data.matrix(b, rownames.force = TRUE) 

C <- A[!apply(A, 1, paste, collapse="$$") %in% apply(B, 1, paste, collapse="$$")]

C # now `C' is simply a string. SO we have to fold it back up, so to speak
[1] NA 11  5  6 14 16

C <- matrix(C, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE, 
            dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("z", "x", "y")))

C
   z x  y
1 NA 5 14
2 11 6 16
```