# How to delete entries in a table that are not in a list

Tags: r

I only know very basic R so forgive me if this has an obvious answer.

So I have a table with two columns (let's call it A) and a table with one column (B). I want RStudio to look through the second column of A and delete each entry that isn't in B. For example if the number 0007 is in the second column of A but it's not in B then 0007's row is deleted.

[I've tried this solution but I don't think it's what I'm looking for since it threw up an error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084719/r-how-to-delete-exclude-rows-in-a-table-that-are-in-another-table)

I figured that it would be some kind of for loop within a for loop but that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below. Hope this helps!

```r
#sample data - (since OP has not provided any sample data I cooked my own)
A <- data.frame(A_col1=c(3,4,5,6,7),
                A_col2=c('abc','qwerty','007','asdf', 'qwerty'))
B <- data.frame(B_col1=c('abc','qwerty','asdf','prem'))

A_new <- A[A$A_col2 %in% B$B_col1,]
A_new
```

Output is:

```
  A_col1 A_col2
1      3    abc
2      4 qwerty
4      6   asdf
5      7 qwerty
```

You can notice that `007` is not present in B so the corresponding row has been stripped off.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
A <- matrix(c("a", "b", "c", "0003", "0007", "0005"), nrow = 3)
B <- matrix(c("0003", "0004", "0005"), nrow = 3)
res <- A[A[, 2] %in% B[, 1], ]
res
         [,1] [,2]  
[1,] "a"  "0003"
[2,] "c"  "0005"
```